# How can I show the home screen on application launch?

Tags: android

I want my application which has only transparent Views, when launched, to show the home screen of the mobile on the backgound instead of the app screen.

I believe this is achieved by using the activity intents in the manifest xml but so far I haven't been able to find a way to do it.

I'd appreciate it if someone could point me to the right direction.

Comment: What use would that be?  If an activity is transparent, you can't interact with what is behind it.

Comment: I don't want to interact with the background, just to create an illusion that someone is at the home screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry.  I misread the question.  I saw the part about only transparent views and took off from there.  It [appears](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) that an intent with `Intent.ACTION_MAIN` and `Intent.CATEGORY_HOME` should launch the home screen.

I'm not sure of the best way to launch first the home screen, then your transparent activity.  If you're doing this from another activity, I'd probably experiment with putting another startActivity() in the first activity's onPause() or onStop().  That is, put a startActivity() for the launcher wherever it belongs, and at the same time, set a variable like isLaunchingTransparentActivity; then in onPause() or onStop(), if isLaunchingTransparentActivity is true, call startActivity() with an intent for the transparent activity.

Alternately, you could create a home screen widget.  If you launch from an app icon, use a non-transparent activity.  If the user presses the widget (which requires being on the home screen), use the transparent one.

Comment: Should the activity be fully invisible?  If the first activity that appears when the app is launched is invisible, then the user sees nothing happen, so it's pretty useless.  On the other hand, if you have other activities that do things, and one of those has some trigger (like a button) that launches the invisible one, then you might need to do some odd things with the back stack to do what you want while still acting the way a user would expect.  If this is supposed to be some sort of "boss" panic button (as some games used to have), doesn't the actual home key make a better one?

Comment: What are the security considerations of an activity that appears to be the home screen and can receive touch and other events?  Even if the foreground app can't know where icons and such are, the ability to have such an activity seems a bit creepy to me.

Comment: @erichamion Seems like I have a habit of not being very clear with my questions. My application is complete, tested and works fine. The first time I launch it from eclipse on the emulator it runs automatically in front of the home screen but if I want to launch it again I have to go to the application screen to do it, right? But then it runs in front of the application screen. I am curious if there is a way to programmatically change to the home screen (it is just for aesthetic reasons as home screens are usually more colorfoul and lively compared to the black backgound of the app screen)

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" /> 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>  This doesn't work. Do I need 2 different intents?

Comment: @Tsarl: Not an intent filter in XML - that would indicate you want to receive that intent (and therefore act as the home screen).  To start the home screen, Java code in your app would create the intent and call startActivity().